# How to execute 2 SSIS packages in Same project simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have 2 streams which receive JSON objects through HTTP. I create 2 **SSIS** packages to PUSH json objects to Streams. I test them individually and they work fine.

Now I want them to execute simultaneously. I try to start 2 instants of SQL Server Data Tools for Visual studio 2013. But I couldn't do that.

I'm working on Windows Server 2012R2. How I can open 2 instants of SSDT for VS13? Or there is any other way to execute SSIS packages simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. Publish them to an SSIS catalog and run them in there. Downside is you don't get interactivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new package called master package. Inside that package you add 2 tasks called Execute Package Tasks. Then you reference each task to your 2 ssis packages you have created. and then you just run your master package.

**Just like this then they will run simultaneously:**

[image]